# Why using getRangeAt() removes some content from selection, in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, selection, textselection, alt

Using Firefox, I can use `window.getSelection()` in order to get the selected text.

If I selected an image, the `alt` attribute is returned.

However, if I use `.getRangeAt(0)`, the selection is returned without the `alt` attribute.

I would like it to be present in my variable, how can I solve this problem, please?

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/Q982A/56/

If you select the whole line, `Hello. :)` is printed first, and then `Hello.`.

Comment: @MartinErnst It only seems to work in Firefox.

Comment: @imtheman excuse, I was distracted by a call. Comment removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to use this range? A range is an object whose `toString` method is the inner text (see [MDN doc - Range.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range.toString)) and not inner HTML which is displayed.

Nevertheless, you have the whole selection in this object and you can visualize it with by creating a fragment with it, for example like this :

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var selRange = sel.getRangeAt(0);
document.getElementById("test").appendChild(selRange.extractContents());
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q982A/64/).

---

EDIT :

You can also use a document fragment like this : http://jsfiddle.net/Q982A/66/ (in order not to use a displayed element)...